# When I call SetA from main and then call show method of class B , Variable value resets to zero

Tags: java, variables, scope, return-value

```
class A
{
 Int a =0;
   public void SetA(){ //setting a value to 20
    a = 20;
   }
}
class B
   {
     public void show(){
      SetA obj =new SetA();
      System.Out.Println(obj.a)
      }
}
```

First from the main method I called SetA method in class A then call show method in class B but even when I set the values for int a it still returns zero. Someone please explain me why is it happening and how can I fix the issue. How can I access variable a from any onther class with the value that is set in SetA method?

Comment: `public void SetA()` is not a constructor, it's a method that you never call. Remove the `void`

Comment: Your code has compile error. You must use constructor for create object of A.

Comment: Also, there is not type "Int". You should use an "int" or an "Integer".

Answer (score 1):

You never invoke the method `SetA` (although you try to use it instead of the `A` constructor).

```
A obj =new A();
obj.SetA();
System.out.println(obj.a);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Ol044P)

Answer (score 1):

The `a` variable in class `A` is an [instance variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable#:%7E:text=In%20object%2Doriented%20programming%20with,similar%20to%20a%20class%20variable.):

> In object-oriented programming with classes, an instance variable is a
> variable defined in a class (i.e. a member variable), for which each
> instantiated object of the class has a separate copy, or instance.

So each instance of class `A` will have a SEPARATE copy of 'a' that changes individually from all the other class `A` instances.

In the `show()` method of class `B`, you are creating a new, SEPARATE instance of class `A` that is different than the instance of `A` that you previously manipulated.  The default value of `a` is zero, which is why that is the only value you'll see.

If you want `show()` to work with a specific instance of `A`, then you'd have to pass in that instance as a parameter:

```
public void show(A someInstanceOfA) {
    System.Out.Println(someInstanceOfA.a)
}
```

Note that we are NOT creating an instance of class `A` with the `new` keyword inside of `show()`.  We are simply manipulating or using the local reference passed in via the `someInstanceOfA` parameter.

Here's a complete example showing how the instance variable `a` is being manipulated by class `B`:

```
public class A
{

   private int a=0;
   
   public void setA(int value) { 
       a = value;
   }
   
   public int getA() {
       return a;
   }
   
}

public class B
{
    
    public void show(A someInstanceOfA) {
        System.out.println("B.show(): a = " + someInstanceOfA.getA());
        someInstanceOfA.setA(10); // this will modify the instance of A and be reflected back in main()
    }
    
}

public class Driver
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A instanceA = new A();
        instanceA.setA(5);
        System.out.println("Before: a = " + instanceA.getA());
        
        B instanceB = new B();
        instanceB.show(instanceA);
        
        System.out.println("After: a = " + instanceA.getA());
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
Before: a = 5
B.show(): a = 5
After: a = 10
```

Comment: Thanks for breaf explanation !